# How do I test the foreign key object on Django model

Tags: django, testing, django-rest-framework

I want to pass foreign key object(Category) on the model(Article) when testing.Currently, I create the category object and then i pass its variable to my article test data.I am currently gettting this error `TypeError: Object of type 'Category' is not JSON serializable.` My goal is to be able to create a category and then pass it into the article test data when testing creation of a new article.Any ideas into how i can implement this properly ?

base_test.py

```
class BaseTest:
    """
    Class contains data to be used for testing
    """

    def __init__(self):

        self.title = "How to tnnrain your flywwwwwwwwwwf"
        self.description = "Ever wondner how toddddd ddddwwwwd?"
        self.body = "You have to benlieve becausedddddddddcf"

        self.category = Category.objects.create(
            title='test category',
        )
        self.category.save()




       """ sample article data """
       self.create_article = {
            "article": {
                "title": self.title,
                "description": self.description,
                "body": self.body,
                "tags": ["reactjs"],
                "category": self.category


            }
        }
```

test_article.py

```
from rest_framework.test import APIClient, APITestCase
from rest_framework import status
from ..test_authentication.test_base import BaseTest
from authors.apps.articles.models import Article, Category
from authors.apps.authentication.models import User

class ArticlesTest(APITestCase,BaseTest):
    def setUp(self):
        BaseTest.__init__(self)
        self.client = APIClient()

    """ method for testing creation of a new article """
    def test_create_article(self):
        self.create_login_user()
        response = self.client.post('/api/articles/',self.create_article, 
        format="json")
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

      class Meta: 
            verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

      def __str__(self):
            return self.title

class Article(models.Model):

      title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)

      slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)

      description = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)

      body = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False,)    

      category = models.ForeignKey(Category, 
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: do it in create method in serializer, please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're simulating an HTTP POST with JSON data, instead of passing the python `Category` object, you should pass the category id:

```
class BaseTest:
"""
Class contains data to be used for testing
"""

    def __init__(self):

       self.title = "How to tnnrain your flywwwwwwwwwwf"
       self.description = "Ever wondner how toddddd ddddwwwwd?"
       self.body = "You have to benlieve becausedddddddddcf"

      self.category = Category.objects.create(
          title='test category',
         )
      # don't need to call save

    self.create_article = {
            "title": self.title,
            "description": self.description,
            "body": self.body,
            "tags": ["reactjs"],
            "category": self.category.id
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

you should convert self.category to json.
It isn't json variable